# replace all variables in string in ksh

Tags: ksh

I have a string ( variable ) that contains some other variables.
I need to replace all this variables to real value.

e.g.:

```
WORD="aaa"

TEXT="bbb"

MY_STRING=`cat temp.file`

# after it MY_STRING contains the below value

# MY_STRING="Hello ${WORD}, how are you ${TEXT}"
```

I want to get the evaluated string

```
 MY_STRING="Hello aaa, how are you bbb"
```

The temp.file can contains different variables ( not only WORD and TEXT )

The variables that I need to replace define with `${NAME}` and not as `$NAME`

Comment: Have you considered using sed?

Comment: I didn't find solution with sed

Answer (score 0):

When WORD and TEXT are part of a seperate file, use a dot to include the content into your environment:

```
. temp.file
```